# Discrete Mathematics - Understanding Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this question on quantifiers which I cannot figure out, any help is much appreciated!

Let P (x), Q(x), and R(x) be the statements “x is a clear explanation,” “x is satisfactory,” and “x is an excuse,” respectively. Suppose that the domain for x consists of all English text. Express each of these statements using quan- tifiers, logical connectives, and P (x), Q(x), and R(x).

```
a) All clear explanations are satisfactory.
b) Some excuses are unsatisfactory.
c) Some excuses are not clear explanations.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for (a): a common error is to write this as
$$\forall x\ (\,P(x) \wedge Q(x)\,)\ .$$
However, this means that for all text, it is a clear explanation and it is satisfactory.  What you actually want to say is that for all text, **if** it is a clear explanation then it is satisfactory.  Can you do this?  (Another hint: you only have to change one symbol in the above incorrect ansswer.)

Comment: im guessing to change $\land$ to $\to$?

Comment: @Sentrl, correct.  Now try something similar (NB it's not the same) for (b).  "There exists text which is an excuse ... it is not satisfactory" - fill in the dots with a word then write it in symbols.